# SQL Permutation of Columns

Tags: sql, join, hive, union, sql-null

I have a purchases table that looks like this:

```
store_id.   industry_code    amt_age_18_24    amt_age_25-34    amt_men    amt_women
       1             1000              100               20         80           40
       2             2000              100              100        130           70
```

What I'm trying to do is find every permutation of purchases by age and gender for each store. Something like this, where each row is unique:

```
store_id.   industry_code    amt_age_18_24    amt_age_25-34    amt_men    amt_women
       1             1000              100             NULL         80          NULL
       1             1000              100             NULL        NULL           40
       1             1000              NULL            20           80          NULL
       1             1000              NULL            20          NULL           80
       2             2000              100             NULL        130          NULL
       2             2000              100             NULL        NULL           70
       2             2000              NULL            100         130          NULL
       2             2000              NULL            100         NULL           70
```

What's the best way to do this? A self join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach using a `cross join` with a derived table that contains "column masks":

```
select 
    t.store_id, 
    t.industry_code, 
    t.amt_age_18_24 * x.amt_age_18_24 as amt_age_18_24,
    t.amt_age_25_34 * x.amt_age_25_34 as amt_age_25_34,
    t.amnt_men      * x.amnt_men      as amnt_men,
    t.amt_women     * x.amt_women     as amt_women
from mytable t
cross join (
    select 1 as amt_age_18_24, null as amt_age_25_34, 1 as amnt_men, null as amt_women
    union all select 1, null, null, 1
    union all select null, 1, 1, null
    union all select null, 1, null, 1
) x
```

The upside is that this does not require scanning the table multiple times, as opposed to the `union all` approach.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like `union all`:

```
select store_id, instrustry_code, amt_age_18_24, null as amt_age_25_34, amt_men, null as amt_women
from t
union all
select store_id, instrustry_code, amt_age_18_24, null as amt_age_25_34, null as amt_men, amt_women
from t
union all
. . .
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use union for each permutation as you wish:

```
select store_id, instrustry_code, amt_age_18_24, null as amt_age_25_34, amt_men, null as amt_women
from t
union all
select store_id, instrustry_code, amt_age_18_24, null as amt_age_25_34, null as amt_men, amt_women
from t
```

and do it for as many columns as you want